# use_sim_time only for some of the running nodes

Tags: ros, use-sim-time, clock

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there some way to enable `use_sim_time` only for dedicated nodes?

I have a scenario in which a node should use the simulated time published on `/clock` while at the same time other nodes are running which should use the wall time.

Since `/use_sim_time` is a global parameter, simply setting it to true would lead to all nodes using the simulated time. I think it would work to first start the wall-time nodes, then set the parameter and after that start the sim-time node, but I would prefer a more robust method, if there is any.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/272339/use_sim_time-only-for-some-of-the-running-nodes/) by [Felix Widmaier](https://answers.ros.org/users/28762/felix-widmaier/) on ROS Answers with karma: 382 on 2017-10-05

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-10-05**:
Can you explain why you feel you need this, just to avoid an xy-problem? Perhaps board members can then assess whether it makes sense to do this.

There is a reason `use_sim_time` is 'a global parameter'.

**Comment by [Felix Widmaier](https://answers.ros.org/users/28762/felix-widmaier/) on 2017-10-05**:
I need a node to process a bagfile (using the clock from the bagfile) while other nodes are running normally (i.e. using the wall-time) on the same machine.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-10-05**:
Ok, so why do the other nodes need to use wall-time?

**Comment by [Felix Widmaier](https://answers.ros.org/users/28762/felix-widmaier/) on 2017-10-05**:
The other nodes do not subscribe to anything published by the bagfile. I have a running system and just a single node (which is completely decoupled from the remaining system) needs to do some processing of a bagfile. Unfortunately it has to run together on the same machine.

**Comment by [Felix Widmaier](https://answers.ros.org/users/28762/felix-widmaier/) on 2017-10-05**:
An idea just came to my mind, maybe I can solve it by running two parallel roscores.

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-10-05**:
Are the other nodes not using data from the bag file?

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2017-10-05**:
It may be better to use the C++ bag API to process the bag file instead of publishing those messages and having a node that subscribes to them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I solved it now by running two separate roscores (see e.g. [this question](https://answers.ros.org/question/57539/how-to-run-multiple-roscoremaster-in-a-single-machine/)). So the nodes using the wall time run with one core and the node using the simulated time runs with the other core.

---

Originally posted by [Felix Widmaier](https://answers.ros.org/users/28762/felix-widmaier/) with karma: 382 on 2017-10-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1